Is there a magnetic field when the area of ​the plates of a capacitor increases?
When a current flows into or out of the capacitor plates, a magnetic field is created between them. Even though there are no charges flowing in the space between the plates, there is still a magnetic field and the source of that field is an uncharged current called a “displacement current”.
Suppose that the parallel plate capacitor with area $A$ is fully charged with a charge $Q$ and disconnected from the source. Then the area of ​​the plates is doubled, then the charge $Q$ will be distributed over twice the initial surface which gives us a smaller electric field $E/2$. Does this variation in the electric field produce a magnetic field?
It depends on which formula I analyze it with and I see a different result.
Using the Ampere-Maxwell equation with the derivative of the electric flux:
$$\oint\vec{B}.d\vec{l} = \mu_{0} I + \mu_{0} \epsilon_{0}\frac{d{\Phi_{E}}}{dt}$$
there is no variation in the electric flux since the area doubles but the electric field decreases by half (that is, I have the same initial flux $EA$) so the right side of the equation is equal to zero.
On the other hand, if I take into account the partial derivative of the electric field:
$$\oint\vec{B}.d\vec{l} = \mu_{0}I + \mu_{0} \epsilon_{0}\int_{S}^{}{\frac{\partial{\vec{E}}}{\partial{t}}.d\vec{S}}$$
there is a change since the electric field decreases by half so the right hand side of the equation is not equal to zero.
I am getting different results. Where am I going wrong?
